# $L^2$ Bound for Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

> Let $X$ be an $L^2$ random variable. Show we can establish the following bound:
>   $$
> \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq \gamma \mathbb{E}[|X|]) \geq (1- \gamma)^2\frac{\mathbb 
> E[|X|]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}
> $$
>   for $0< \gamma <1$.

I am thinking this has something to do with Chebyshev's inequality, however I'm not sure. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Maybe start by thinking about the nonnegative case...there are some issues about signs here.

Comment: I've made (what I think are) the necessary adjustments.

Comment: This is a well-known inequality -- would you just like to know the proof or a hint towards one?

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda a hint with a (censored) full answer would be much appreciated. I'm not entirely sure even where to begin

Comment: Sure! The inequality is called the Paley-Zygmund inequality and is the prototypical anti-concentration bound. Following the proof on the wikipedia page for this, try writing $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X 1_{\{X\leq\gamma\mathbb E[X]\}}] + \mathbb E[X1_{\{X>\gamma\mathbb E[X]\}}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, for a contradiction, that for some $\gamma\in (0,1)$,
    $$
P(|X|>\gamma E(|X|))<(1-\gamma)^2\frac{E[|X|]^2}{E[X^2]}
$$
    Observe that
    $$
E[|X|]^2=(E(|X|\mid |X|=0)+E(|X|\mid |X|>0))^2=E(|X|\mid |X|>0)^2
$$
    More formally,
    $$
E|X|=\int_{\Omega}|X|\chi_{|X|>0}dp\leq \|X\|_2\sqrt{P(|X|>0)}
$$
    by Cauchy-Schwarz-Teichmueller. Hence
    $$
E[|X|]^2\leq \|X\|_2^2P(|X|>0)=P(|X|>0)E(X^2)
$$
    Therefore, our assumption yields
    $$
P(|X|-\gamma E(|X|)>0)<(1-\gamma)^2P(|X|>0)
$$
    and taking the expectation on both sides, we have
    $$
E(|X|-\gamma E(|X|))=(1-\gamma)E(|X|)<(1-\gamma)^2E(|X|)
$$
    which is a contradiction since $\gamma\in (0,1)$.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks this really did help!

Comment: "Taking the expectation on both sides..." How does that change anything if both sides are constants?

Comment: @CaveJohnson--you're right, I could have been clearer. integrate |X| over the LHS domain, and the same on the RHS. Consider approximating by simple functions on the right to get the last line.